# How can I convert some of my strings into integers, then do math with them in Python?

Tags: python

I keep getting syntax errors whenever I try to convert the string "discount1" to convert it to "actualDiscount" into the program. Say you input "30|.15|0-Clothes" into the program:

```
product1 = raw_input("Enter the information for the first product>")

space1 = product1.find("|")
space2 = product1.rfind("|")
price1=product1[0:space1]
discount1=product1[space1+1:space2]
category1 = product1[space2+1:len(product1)]
actualPrice = int(price1)
actualDiscount = int(discount1)
printNow("Price is " + int(actualPrice))
printNow("Discount is " + int(actualDiscount) + " percent.")
```

Sometimes, depending on what I enter as input, it can manage to work all the way up to the printNows. Other times, it can't even get that far.

On top of it all, I have to do math with these integers-- subtract the price from the price multiplied by the discount percentage. I'm a little lost to say the least, and some help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Show us the actual errors you're getting.  Saying "it doesn't work" tells us almost nothing.

Comment: You "have to do math with integers", then why are you inputting float values like `.15`?

Answer (score 1):

First, it may be easier to parse your fields using split: `data = product1.split( "|" )`

Second, ".15" is not an `int`.  Convert it using `float()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to comment your code and try to explain errors or modifications you can do.

```
product1 = raw_input("Enter the information for the first product>")

# Instead of find/rfind, you can split by '|'
```

Replace this:

```
space1 = product1.find("|")
space2 = product1.rfind("|")
price1=product1[0:space1]
discount1=product1[space1+1:space2]
category1 = product1[space2+1:len(product1)]
```

by this:

```
# You get a list: ['30', '.15', '0-Clothes']
data = product1.split("|")
```

After that, you have to apply data transformations:

```
# Price is an integer
actualPrice = int(data[0])

# Discount is a float
actualDiscount = float(data[1)]

# Category
category = data[2]
```

And then, print the results:

```
print("Price is " + int(actualPrice))
print("Discount is " + int(actualDiscount) + " percent.")
```

#### Optimizing code

I think you want to generalize that code to process more than one item "a|b|c". You can use **list comprehension** to simplify your code as follows:

```
# Data input
product1 = raw_input("Enter the information for the first product>")

# Data 
data = [ [int(price),float(discount),category] for price, count, category in [product1.split("|")]]

for actualPrice, actualDiscount, category in data:
    print("Price is " + str(actualPrice))
    print("Discount is " + str(actualDiscount) + " percent.")
    print("Final price is " + str(actualPrice - actualPrice * actualDiscoun$
```

This is how a comprehension list works:

```
list_name = [ elements_you_want_to_get for list_element(s) in another_list ]
```

Creates a list iterating over `another_list` and gets it elements using the `list_element(s)` selection, which allows to assign values our custom names. Then, in `elements_you_want_to_get` you can apply transformations over data.

Explained by each element:

- `[product1.split("|")]` : creates a list with splitted data. We surround the split result with brackets to make a list of type [[item1, item2, item3]] in order to create a structure with elements composed by 3 sub elements. For the example, now we have:

> > [['30', '.15', '0-Clothes']]

Note that this list of list of 3 subelements each one is the `another_list` element of list comprehension I showed you.

- `for price, count, category` : for each element of `another_list` the loop gets each element (in our case is only `['30', '.15', '0-Clothes']`) and names it's sub elements as price, discount and category. At this time we have `price='30'`, `discount='.15'` and `category='0-Clothes'`.
- The last step, the comprehension applies transformations. In our case we want to convert `price` in integer and `discount` in float (to avoid incompatibilities, the changes should be all to float).

After the comprehension, the result is:

> > [[price_1, discount_1, category_1], [price_2, discount_2, category_2], ...]

In our case, we only have one element, and the result would be:

`data = [....]

> > [[30, 0.15, '0-Clothes]]

Note that the result list has two numeric elements and one string element (surrounded by quotes).